# Python script to search and display data from sqlite database and result formated results to screen

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a very basic script below which searches a database table and retrieves data depend on what is input then displays the result but the results are comma delimited with quotes around each field is there a way it can be better displayed may be using html.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("lucyartists.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Get user input
print ('Search for an Artist')
print ('')
print ('You can search by Name, DOB, Movement or Description')
print ('')
name = input("Enter Artists Name: ")
dob = input("Enter Date of Birth: ")
movement = input("Enter Movement: ")
description = input ("Enter Description: ")
sql = ("select * from artists where name like (?) or dob like (?) or  movement like (?) or description like (?)")
values = (name, dob, movement, description)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
print(r)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: Simple formatting can be achieved by using tabs. HTML can be generated easily as well.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `print(r)` needs to be indented. Python code blocks are defined by their indentation.

See the documentation on str.format [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Example below with 4 fields:

```
for r in result:
    print("Name: {}".format(r["name"])
    print("DOB: {}".format(r["dob"])
    print("Movement: {}".format(r["movement"])
    print("Description: {}".format(r["description"])
    print() # extra line between rows of output
```

You could do this all on one line as follows:

```
for r in result:
    print("Name: {} DOB: {} Movement: {} Description: {}".format(r["name"], r["dob"], r["movement"]), r["description"])
    print() # extra line between rows of output
```